# How to use Ivy iBiblio resolver to connect to SPNEGO protected Maven repository?

Tags: ant, maven-3, artifactory, ivy, spnego

Within our organisation servers are protected using SPNEGO (Kerberos for HTTP), with Apache HTTPD handling this (one per application server). This is also the case for our JFrog Artifactory server.

There is a use case where we need to use ant to pull artifacts from the server, using the Ivy iBiblio resolver, but it does not seem to work for us, given this scenario. Essentially authentication fails.

Does anyone know how to configure the resolver to use non-username/password auth, specifically using SPNEGO?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Since Ivy runs off Apache HttpClient you will suffer from HTTPCLIENT-1625.